# NullPointerException on attempting to filter with SimpleAdapter

Tags: android

I have an Activity with a ListView that uses a SimpleAdapter. Here is the onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_selection);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mContactsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
    mContactAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, getEmailContacts(), R.layout.contact_list_item,
            new String[] { CONTACT_FIELDS.NAME.toString(), CONTACT_FIELDS.PHOTOURI.toString(),
                    CONTACT_FIELDS.SECONDARY_DATA.toString(), CONTACT_FIELDS.TYPE.toString() },
            new int[] { R.id.contact_name, R.id.contact_image, R.id.contact_type_name,
                    R.id.contact_type_name });
    mContactsList.setAdapter(mContactAdapter);
}
```

This works fine; the list shows up and is filled properly. Let me emphasize that--the problem is not with my getEmailContacts() method being null, since the list gets rendered properly at this point.

I'm trying to add filtering though, and so I add this line after mContactsList.setAdapter to try it out:

```
    mContactAdapter.getFilter().filter("Ca");
```

This results in a crash, with the following stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:712)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:835)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AbsListView.java:5966)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:50)
    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:59)
    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter.publishResults(SimpleAdapter.java:383)
    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestions? Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your getEmailContacts() method is returning a null object. Looking at the SimpleAdapter source, the getCount method just calls mData.size(), where mData is the List of Maps of data that you passed in to the SimpleAdapter constructor via the getEmailContacts() method.

Comment: No, that is not the case. Like I said, it works fine until I call the filtering method.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that - I missed that part of your question. I was hoping it would be that easy :). From looking at the source, it appears the filter method changes the mData object to be the FilterResults.values object. This ends up being null somehow.

Comment: Yeah, but how, therein is the question. ;)

Comment: If you have downloaded the source (you can do it via the SDK Manager), you could try stepping through the SimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter code to see where the null object is being set.

Comment: Yeah, I have the source, I was just hoping someone else would know (and am working on something else in the meantime) but it's looking increasingly like I'm going to have to dive in.